# Using jQuery to check if radio button is not checked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to the label of radio button. The class that is added varys depending on whether the button is selected or not. How do I test for a not checked status?

```
if (ui.item.Status) {
    $('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]')[0].checked = true;
} else {
    $('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]')[1].checked = true;
}
$('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]:checked').parent().addClass('btn-success');
$('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]:!checked').parent().addClass('btn-failure');
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Use `:not(:checked)`.

Comment: Try using the `.not()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this instead by using function callback of `addClass`

```
var elem = $(':radio[name="StatusType.Active"]');
elem.parent().addClass(function(){
   return "btn-" + (elem.is(":checked") ? "success" : "failure");
});
```

Comment: It never removes the class, but neither does the OP's code, so good answer.

Comment: Note that the class should be added to the parent element, not the radio ?

Comment: are you in school @AmitJoki? I recently saw ur linked profile

Comment: Oh no, `$(this).end()` will never work, there's nothing to end

Comment: Why are you using `end`?

Comment: @AmitJoki about edit: it should be `input:radio[name='StatusType.Active']` or at least `:radio[name='StatusType.Active']`.

Comment: Nope, `end` only returns the previous in a chain, as in `$('div').find('span').end()`, which goes back to `div`, you can't do `$(this).end()` as jQuery has no idea what to go back to

Comment: thanks guys.. thought .end() would work in the same way as `$(":radio").parent().css(...).end()`

Comment: @AmitJoki +1 for `var selector`. Just to mention: I suppose that slightly rewritten code [in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLa2s1dg/1/) is "better written" code.

Comment: @Regent yeah! That's is great one too. But I'll let your comment say that. +1 for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method in jQuery

```
$('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]').not(':checked').parent().addClass('btn-failure');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector with the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) method as follows:

```
var $checkbox = $('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]');
if($checkbox.is(':checked'))
   $checkbox.parent().addClass('btn-success');
else
   $checkbox.parent().addClass('btn-failure');
```

Answer (score 0):

something like `:not` :-

```
$('input:radio[name="StatusType.Active"]:not(:checked)').parent().addClass('btn-failure');
```